# issubset when one array is two dimensional

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have two **sets**, I need to get true if both of('z' and 'y') are in one of the tuples in B, but I cannot figure it out.
Is there any solution to get true from this? the order of each tuple in A and B is not important to me.

```
A = {('z', 'y')}
B = {('x', 'y'), ('y', 'z'), ('a', 'b')}
```

my code is:

```
if ((set(A)).issubset(B)):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Generally, it checks whether A `issubset` in **each tuple of B.**

Comment: Neither `'z'` nor `'y'` is in `B`, so `A` can't be a subset of `B`. "…in one of the tuples in B…" is not how sets work in Python.

Comment: "Generally, it checks whether A issubset *in each tuple of* B." No. It checks whether A is a subset of B. Why do you expect otherwise?

Comment: you are right but I want to change my code to get true. I can also change A to {('z' , 'y')}. Do you have any idea? @jtbandes

Comment: You could try to change A to `A = {'z', 'y' }` then looping each in B.

Comment: And in your original code, you did not check each tuple in B.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition of Subset:**
Set `A` is subset of Set `B` if `B` includes all of the Set `A`'s member.

Here member of set `B` are tuples, and the members of `A` are strings, so it is obvious that set `A` won't be the subset of `B`.

This would be true if the set `A` was like this:

```py
A={('y', 'z')}
```

even `A={('z', 'y')}` will result `false`, since `('z', 'y')` is not equal to `('y', 'z')`

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea that how can I get true from A={('y', 'z')} or A={('z', 'y')}? because the order of each tuple is not important to me.

Comment: Consider change A to a real set: `{ 'z', 'y'}`